# DataBase creation for small size file but large in number

Tags: database, mongodb, bigdata, data-science, hdf5

I am having very large number of file with small size which may be structured (Json, csv) or may be unstructured(video).
I want to create database which will consolidate all these files in systematic way, Which can be used for data analytics purpose in future.

So far, I have been considering HDF5, MongoDB for getting this task done .

Please suggest some other options inline with the above scenario and which one would be best among HDF5 and MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

In my point of views you can stores all files in HDFS but regarding unstructured(Video) MangoDB would be the best.

Comment: Thanks shubham, But here i am finding an complete solution for this thing. Can you share your views about Cassandra in this scenario.